Cannot use Cintiq after un-sleeping or restarting computer
Nine times out of ten, if I power cycle or sleep my computer, my cintiq becomes unresponsive (the cursor will not follow the stylus).
The only way I have found that I can reliably get my cintiq to work is to restart the computer, then, when Ubuntu is running, I unplug the cintiq's USB, and reconnect it.
After doing this, the cintiq will work.
Is there any command I can run to avoid physically disconnecting and reconnecting the plug?
Is there anything I can do to avoid this problem altogether?
I'm running Ubuntu 22.04

is opentabletdriver installed

What's a "cintiq"? I infer that it's a USB device. Start by watching sudo journalctl  --follow as you plug in your "cintiq". Look at your system startup log (watch your kernel discover the hardware) with the terminal command sudo journalctl  -b 0. Read man journalctl.

killertofus, how do I find out if I have that installed?
I think I've been using a PPA for my driver. It hasn't been updated recently, and I don't think it supports 24.04. So that's maybe the problem?
https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/doctormo/wacom-plus/ubuntu
I tried removing it with
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:doctormo/wacom-plus
but it doesn't execute, and doesn't return any error. I also tried
sudo ppa-purge ppa:doctormo/wacom-plus
That gives me an error message saying
Warning: apt-get update failed for some reason
:-(
